# Static navbar&footer with nodejs jade and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to render dynamic content between my static navbar and footer upon clicking the links in my navbar, but every time I click a link it duplicates the content including the navbar and footer. I'm using node with express and the jade template engine.

This is my (simplified) top-most jade file.

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        // { links }
    body
        block navbar
            #navLinks.nav.navbar-nav
                    a(href='/', id='home') Home
                    a(href='/ourteam', id='team') Our Team
                    a(href='/blog', id='blog') Blog
        #pageBody
            block content
        block footer
            // { footer content }
    // { scripts }
```

My jQuery AJAX script:

```
$('#navLinks').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hello world");

    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    updatePage(url);

});

function updatePage(url) {

    var pageBody = $('#pageBody');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(html) {
        console.log(html);
        pageBody.html(html);
    });
}
```

The issue is that whenever I click any of the links in my navbar it duplicates the navbar inside the #pageBody div. I'm assuming it's because the content files the router routes to extends my top-level file. I've been trolling the web for an answer and can't find any solution.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with loading files that don't include your navbar? (IE, only the `content`)

Comment: The navbar is then duplicated inside the content itself for some reason when I try loading files that don't include the navbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave the answer yourself with saying "*assuming it's because the content files ... extend my top-level file*". @jraede is absolutely right in asking what is stopping you from loading *partials*.

Get the big picture: Your routes are apparently invoking actions which render "classic" full page html responses. Therefore your specific jade templates probably extend the "top-most" layout file as shown with the code quoted in your question. This is nice for directly requesting - let's say `http://your-project.tld/ourteam` - within your browser.

But now you want to render only *partials* and transfer only this partial html code via ajax/xhr, eventually replacing only the html inside your `#pageBody` div. One way to achieve this would be to define additional routes/actions and jade templates. Try this receipe:

1. Create a partial template `partials/ourteam-content.jade`.
2. Put only the relevant *content* inside of it (copied from block content inside `ourteam.jade`), don't extend your main layout, don't
   use a block definition here.
3. To keep things clean, modify your original `ourteam.jade` and just include the newly created partial template right below your block definition:

   ```
   block content
     include patials/ourteam-content
   ```
4. Define another route/action and name it `/ourteam-content`.
5. On `app.get("ourteam-content", ...)` render only your `partials/ourteam-content` template.
6. Re-route your ajax request for "our team" to query `ourteam-content`.

I hope it helps to push you into the right direction!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was completely unaware of jade partials.

Comment: @slepnerp It's up to you - nobody tells you how partials are defined, neither does jade.